# Unboundedness of ODE with trigonometric coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometric-integrals

The task I am working on involves proving that the solutions to the system

$$\dot x  = \begin{pmatrix}\cos{t} & \sin{t} \newline \sin{t} & -\cos{t}\end{pmatrix}x$$

are unbounded. To start I introduced the new variable $z = x_1 + ix_2$ and reformulated the system of ODE's to:

$$\dot z = \bar z ·e^{it}$$

The solution can be found as shown by a collegue before, but it seems to be too complex for what is required from the task. I would be happy for any tips and suggestions that you can give me.

Comment: Funny story, if unboundedness is all you want to prove then the last solution was actually not far off. However, I suggest keeping this question up so that someone can give a more traditional or clever approach to showing unboundedness rather than brute force.

Comment: Can you please confirm the signs in the matrix?

Comment: @maxmilgram I can confirm the coefficients signs to the extend that they are the ones given in the problem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2530649/115115 for the complete solution. This shows indeed that all solution are exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without complex numbers. Taking the magnitude squared on both sides we have that

$$\dot{x}_1^2 + \dot{x}_2^2 = (x_1 \cos t + x_2 \sin t)^2 + (x_1 \sin t - x_2 \cos t)^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2$$

which means

$$|x| = |\dot x| \geq \dot{|x|}$$

This is true for any vector but is most easily seen in polar coordinates where $|\dot{x}| = \sqrt{\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2}$ but $\dot{|x|} = \dot{r}$. The unboundedness result follows from Gronwall's inequality, either towards $+\infty$ for growth or $-\infty$ for decay.

Comment: Thanks @NinadMunshi . May I kindly ask you to give a short explanation on the conclusion and how to apply Gronwall's inequality here?

Comment: @PabloJeken Technically I went too far at the end of the chain of inequalities, what I could have is $|x| \geq | \dot{|x|}|$. The value $|x|$ is a function $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$. Denoting it as $f$, it is easier to see that $$f \geq | \dot{f} | \implies f(x) \geq f(0) e^{|x|}$$ which is what comes from Gronwall inequality (or just normal inequalities). I might have applied the inequality a little loosely or little too laxly on the sign cases for the derivative, but the rigorous argument is not far off from this.